# How do I wire an ascx event from a dynamically loaded ascx page into the aspx page...?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

This piece of code is in my ASPX page. The snippet shown below is used to dynamically load user controls based on certain selections made by the user on the ASPX page.

```
    protected void loadUserControl(string tmUCName)
    {
        phDetail.Controls.Clear();
        ViewState["vsControl"] = null;
        UserControl tmUControl = LoadControl(tmUCName) as UserControl;
        tmUControl.ID = "ucidControl";
        phDetail.Controls.Add(tmUControl);
        ViewState["vsControl"] = tmUCName;
    }
```

The ASCX works, and so does the SELECT event on the ASCX page. My problem is getting the value from the select event on the ASCX page to the ASPX page. As the user control (ASCX) is loaded dynamically (based on certain selections on the ASPX page), I am finding it hard to wire the events from the ASCX into the ASPX page. In an explicit load situation, I have no problems... everything is pretty peachy...

For what it's worth, if the pages were explicitly loaded, example:

```
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Clear();
WebUserControlTest02 = LoadControl(@"~\WebUserControl2.ascx") as WebUserControl2;
WebUserControlTest02.gvASCX02SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler (WebUserControlTest02_gvASCX02SelectedIndexChanged);
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(WebUserControlTest02);
```

I have no problems with wiring events between ASPX and ASCX pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: There are two parts to the question and answer. The first part is how to ["bubble"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018350/c-sharp-bubbling-passing-along-an-event) an event that occurs on a control inside the `UserControl`. This is accomplished by handling the inner control's event and then firing a similar event on the `UserControl` itself. In this case the `UserControl's` event shares the same name and signature as the inner control's event. This is not a requirement, but in this case it makes sense to do so.

The second part is how to dynamically load `UserControls` yet still have the containing web page hook up to this bubbled event that is defined on each of the `UserControl` classes. The problem is that the ASP.NET `UserControl` class itself does not define the event, and the only common aspect of the dynamically loaded `UserControls` is the fact that they are all of type `UserControl`.
This problem is solved by also having all of the `UserControls` implement a common interface that defines the event. By casting the `UserControl` variable to the interface type, you get access to the event that the interface defines. And at that time you can hook up the web page to handle the event.

Together, these two parts allow the event that originated in a `ListBox` control to be repeated by the `UserControl` that contains the `ListBox`, and for the web page which has dynamically loaded the `UserControl` to listen for and respond to the same event.

---

First define an interface with the event that you want handled:

```
public interface IMyUserControl
{
    event EventHandler SelectedIndexChanged;

}
```

Next, have each of your UserControls implement this event and wire up the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the listbox:

```
public partial class WebUserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl, IMyUserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += (o, args) =>
        {
            var selectedIndexChanged = SelectedIndexChanged;
            if (selectedIndexChanged != null)
                selectedIndexChanged(o, args);
        };
    }

    public event EventHandler SelectedIndexChanged;
}
```

Now in your common code, cast the UserControl as the interface type and viola, you have access to the Event:

```
protected void loadUserControl(string tmUCName)
{
    phDetail.Controls.Clear();
    ViewState["vsControl"] = null;
    UserControl tmUControl = LoadControl(tmUCName) as UserControl;
    tmUControl.ID = "ucidControl";
    phDetail.Controls.Add(tmUControl);
    ViewState["vsControl"] = tmUCName;
    ((IMyUserControl)tmUControl).SelectedIndexChanged += OnUserControlSelectedIndexChanged
}

private void OnUserControlSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Keith, appreciate the feedback. I think I got the hang of it, but I am a bit confused. 

In the interface example that you described -- is "SelectedIndexChanged" the control event, or a eventhandler name? I tried giving the event a sensible name, but that refused to get exposed in the ASCX. Requesting an elaboration on the interface, and how that ties up with the ASCX.

Comment: Keith, I haven't reached the level to markup your response, so for now my comment is it... :)

Comment: SelectedIndexChanged is the control event. The UserControl is handling the SelectedIndexChanged event raised by the ListBox (which is inside the UserControl) and "bubbling" it up to the web page.